# Syntax Problem in Parameterized Query Using pg-promise and node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I've been working on a project with nodejs and pg-promise. Couldn't quite figure out how to implement parameterized query. Here how my code looks like:

```
 // let's say we have an array
 var hex = new Array;
 hex = [[0, 1, 2, 'string1', 3, 'string2'],[4, 5, 6, 'string3', 7, 'string4']];
 //lets assume db is initialized with correct parameters and we have a for loop
 for (var i=0; i<hex.length; i++){
    db.tx(t => {
       return t.batch([
           t.none('INSERT INTO x (lat, long, name) VALUES ($1[$2][0], $1[$2][1],
                  $1[$2][4];)',[hex,i]),
           t.none('DELETE FROM x WHERE name='y'; ')];
   )}
   .then(data => {})
   .catch(error => {
          console.log('ERROR:', error);
   });
   )
}
```

My guess is that I'm not coding in right syntax especially in

```
t.none('INSERT INTO x (lat, long, name) VALUES ($1[$2][0], $1[$2][1], $1[$2][4];)',[hex,i]
```

I've read about the difference between passing arrays and parameters-functions in Vitaly's documentation. But couldn't merge them together since I'm guessing I need them both.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: btw I'm getting syntax error near '['.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are formatting queries in a very unusual way, very difficult to see what it is you are trying to get in the first place. You should diagnose it on your side, using [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), and then you should be able to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it! What basically I'm trying to do is that I'm trying to add index 0, 1 and 4 of `hex` to a db but do it iteratively since length of hex is more than one  by doing this: `t.none('INSERT INTO x (lat, long, name) VALUES (hex[i][0], hex[i][1], hex[i][4];) `

Comment: That is messy. You should start using [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), so you can see what queries you are executing.